# To complete tasks at work I have to ignore new email, yet still reference old email to get the task done

Tags: email, time-management

I'm having a time management issue. To complete my technical work, I find it helpful to close my email tab. This gives me quiet time to get work done without feeling compelled to look at my inbox and deal with interrupts.

Unfortunately my job role has changed such that I have to reference information sent to me in email. I used to be driven entirely by a ticketing system. For example getting server IPs or reviewing updated requirements sent as an email. This means I have to have my email open and searchable to find information.

How can I manage this conflict?

Is there a general strategy?

Are there specific tools, plugins, software or settings that might help?

I am open to both technical and psychological solutions.

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem here is that you *feel compelled* to read an email just because it's sitting in your inbox?

Comment: Yes. For example, I am working on a task that requires some information a user sent me yesterday. I've got that message open and moving along with my task. As I'm looking at the users email I got 2 new messages, the inbox counter changed, and I have a hard time not clicking to see what the new messages are.

Comment: My corporate overlord uses gmail and I use the browser if that matters.

Comment: This sounds like it's simply an issue of self control.  I suppose you could seek professional help for something like that, but I don't believe there are any technical solutions.

Comment: Save out the information into a file or forward it to a 2nd email account.

Comment: @ChrisLively Simply an issue? If self control was easy we would never procrastinate, never eat too much, never sleep in too late, never avoid a difficult conversation etc...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about personal productivity.

Comment: This might be a little bit of a silly question, but can you just pull the network cable out? Assuming everything you need is in the emails and not online, this sounds somewhat reasonable

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - Not a bad plan but won't work for me. I telecommute as a software architect and my employer uses Gmail. My tasks require connectivity, my email is not sync'd offline (although maybe it should be!).

Comment: @JimG. might be right. http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2079/is-workplace-productivity-on-topic-on-the-workplace-se/2081#2081

Comment: @Freiheit You can set Gmail up offline

Comment: Email is a key tool in many workplaces.  I don't see how a question about focusing on work and avoiding the distractions of incoming email is off-topic.

Comment: If you are on Gmail, why don't you just use Filters?

Comment: I am using filters 2/3 of new messages never touch my inbox. My inbox is near zero. This oddly makes new emails MORE visible than before anything that does show up in my inbox is actually an email from a person that really does need my attention.

Answer (score 11):

Start getting into a Zero Inbox habit.

1. Things that need to be saved for future reference go into a folder other than the inbox.
2. Shut off any auto notifications.
3. Open the reference folder during down times and not the inbox.

I think a better habit is getting those emails messages out of your email system completely and into Evernote or some other information management system.  They usually have better search tools.

Answer (score 7):

Use an email client, such as Outlook. Set it to send/receive only when you request it. Now you can open the app to look at emails, without getting new ones.

Alternatively, stop using your email as a place to find things. When you get requirements, IP addresses, etc, paste them into a document that you keep on your machine and can read at will.

Comment: If you use Microsoft Outlook you can send an email to a OneNote document (or Evernote) with a single click from the Outlook toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

I would say copy content away from your email or open messages as new tabs away from the inbox.

I would recommend against stopping new emails coming in or notifying you automatically. Because that's when you start polling for them. This is known as operant conditioning with intermittent reinforcement, which will turn the send and receive button into a compulsion. If you do want to turn off emails do it for short periods and don't poll.